# how can i take desired input from textbox in vb?

Tags: vb.net

i have some data in a notepad. i am reading the data and write into the  TextBox .   But i want to take some value which is required. The Data Are Saved Line by line  And Each value is separated by comma. Longitude and latitude is inside in it .how  can i took it from textBox or use this ??

```
Dim fileReader As String
fileReader = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText("E:\Satyajit\Newfolder\13-05-2015.txt")
TextBox1.Text = fileReader
```

suggest any idea ????? i can not think

Comment: Your question title doesn't seem to match the actual issue in your post. Additionally, the code you posted (although it might be related as a part of your project) is not related to your issue. Please post a sample of the data in the file you are reading, as well as the code you've tried to solve your actual problem. You can read this page for help: [ask]

Comment: Show us some data from your text file.

Comment: 13-05-2015,00:01:45,911322457306666,13.1752,77.30059 like this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try splitting the filereader string into parts and then using contains to see if it has the longitude values you are looking for:

```
    TextBox1.Clear()
    Dim fileReader As String
    fileReader = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText("E:\Satyajit\Newfolder\13-05-2015.txt")
    Dim SplitLines = Split(fileReader, vbCrLf)
    For Each SplitLine In SplitLines
        If SplitLine.Contains("Longitude: ") Or SplitLine.Contains("Latitude: ") Then
            TextBox1.Append(SplitLine & vbCrLf)
        End If
    Next
```

Update based on OP's comment:
assuming that you have found the line that contains the longitude you need to split the line based on the comma delimiter:

```
For Each SplitLine In SplitLines
    If SplitLine.Contains("Longitude: ")Then
        Dim LongitudeValue = Split(SplitLine,",")(1)
        TextBox1.Append("Longitude: " & LongitudeValue & vbCrLf)
    End If
Next
```

The same technique would then be applied to the rest of your requirements.

Comment: In that file only value are written like   Date,Time,Constant Number ,Lonitude,Latitude

Comment: I have to only take the value ? ? ?...There are  splitted by  comma